# Only selectors on JMSCorrelationID are currently supported

Tags: go, ibm-mq

Hi im currently using the [mq-golang-jms20](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang-jms20) library for golang to connect to a ibm queue, but im trying to create a consumer with the "JMSMessageID" selector but the library is giving me the "Only selectors on JMSCorrelationID are currently supported" does anybody knows how else could i consume a specific message using the message Id from the queue ?

Comment: I looks like you already did what I was going to suggest and opened a issue on the github repo: [#46](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang-jms20/issues/46).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for submitting this as a [git issue](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang-jms20/issues/46).

I've merged a PR to allow get by `JMSMessageID` today, so if you pull down the latest library from `main` you should be all set!